# Issue with Pandas DataFrame creating

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-analysis

I created a successful df, however, there's something wrong with the column names. they are not on the same row.

Anyone can give some advices? Appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first "Column" isn't a column.  It's an index.

pandas wants to differentiate between the name of the index `"Industry"` and the name of the columns `"YTD_change"`.  So it put's them on different lines.  It's purely formatting.

Try:

```
df.reset_index()
```